How do I merge Facebook Ads API data with GA4 data so that spend data is appropriately attributed to source / medium data?
I am merging Facebook Ads API data with GA4 data. I am matching up the data based on campaign name matches between the two data sets. However, in the GA4 data there are records where the campaign name is associated with different source / medium values. Thus, when I merge the data, I am getting near-duplicate records except for the source / medium values. This is problematic because I have a spend column in the Facebook data and that data is being duplicated and consequently attributed to two different source / medium values. For example, I might have a spend value of $10.00 associated with a specific campaign. But now I have two records containing that spend value and campaign name but associated with two different source / medium values, say "facebook / cpc" and "fb / paid". The issue is that the spend value ideally be distributed across those source / medium values, say $6.00 for one and $4.00 for the other. Is there any way to get the granularity of the source / medium values from the Facebook Ads API so that the spend value is broken down to the source / medium level?
Here is a screenshot of the near-duplicated data. The near-duplicate rows are stacked together in the screenshot (you can tell by them having the same "idx" value).
screenshot of merged data
I tried merging the data by concatenating the source / medium values into a single comma-separated string, but it doesn't solve the problem of breaking out the spend at the source / medium level.
I'm new to all this, so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

add some screenshot about your problem, pls

screenshots and code required

At first glance it looks like the source / medium parameter is trying to pass through a dynamic variable for platform and/or placement. Seeing “an” for audience network and “IG” for Instagram populating under source specifically.
My best guess is that this might be causing the duplicate spend to appear if the API is unable to associate different spend levels by the placement or platform variable. I know in general, even when not sending engine data, adding variables like platform or placement makes the data look messy on GA so this could be what’s causing your issue.
If you are adding a dynamic variable for the source value, I’d consider hard coding it to a single value, such as Meta or Facebook. That way source / medium will always come through as Meta / Paid or Facebook / Paid.
With that, it’s important to make sure that all ads are using the same UTMs, especially for the source / medium part.
There are times where GA4 can show alternative or default parameters for source / medium if users opt out of tracking and data cannot be collected, but ensuring consistency across the account will hopefully eliminate most of this duplication.
Hope this helps!
